# Key Based SingleThreadExecutor

Tags: multithreading, executorservice

Any implementation for a Key Based Thread Pool Executor. The idea is a Thread is dedicated for a specific key. New requests for the same Key  waits till the previous request finishes. If another request comes which evaluates to another key , it can be served by another thread

Comment: This site is not for asking implementation, but help with your implementation. Have you tried doing something? What problems have you encountered?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own map of  and then lookup a ExecutorService for your key or create a new one with Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() when needed. Pass runnables to the singlethreadexecutor as they come, all request for one key will go to the same executor and will be executed sequentially.